# How can I create new rows to the existing DataFrame? in PySpark or Scala

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

For example, now I have this DataFrame.

```
+--------+------+
|      id|number|
+--------+------+
|19891201|     1|
|19891201|     4|
+--------+------+
```

But I want this DataFrame to be like this.

```
+--------+------+
|      id|number|
+--------+------+
|19891201|     1|
|19891201|     2|
|19891201|     3|
|19891201|     4|
+--------+------+
```

I want to create the new rows which have the numbers range from the min() and max() values from the column "number".

In this example, I want to have rows whose values in column "number" are 2 and 3.

Comment: spark version ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sequence(start, stop, step)` function from spark `2.4+` version.

```
scala> df
 .groupBy($"id")
 .agg(
         min($"number").as("start"),
        max($"number").as("end")
    )
 .selectExpr(
        "id",
        "explode_outer(sequence(start,end,1)) as number"
    )
 .show(false)
```

Output

```
+--------+------+
|id      |number|
+--------+------+
|19891201|1     |
|19891201|2     |
|19891201|3     |
|19891201|4     |
+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, FloatType, StringType, IntegerType

from pyspark.sql.functions import min, max , udf, explode

schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),StructField("number", IntegerType(), True)])
my_list = [(19891201, 1), (19891201,4)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(my_list)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.show()
df2 = df.groupby("id").agg(min("number").alias("min"),max("number").alias("max"))

def my_udf(min, max):
    return list(range(min,max+1))

label_udf = udf(my_udf, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df3 = df2.withColumn("l", label_udf(df2.min, df2.max)

df4 = df3.withColumn("ll", explode("l"))
df5 = df4.select("id", "ll")
df5.show()
```